# Countdown timer pause and resume buttons with true or false if statement not working

Tags: javascript, html

`this.start` is the function that starts the countdown. The countdown is only supposed to work if session is `true`. `this.pause` makes the session `false`, and is supposed to stop `this.start`, but the timer never stops; it just keeps counting down.

The function works in the console though. `this.resume` also does nothing; the the counter just keeps going down, although it's supposed to work when session is `true`.

Before I was using `setInterval` for the countdown, and it worked, but I couldn't figure out how to resume it after that. Is there any reason why my `if` statement isn't working here to pause and resume the countdown timer?

```js
let timer = function(sessionNumber2) {
  let session = true;
  console.log(Boolean(session));
  let currentInterval;

  //update counter every 1 second
  if (session == true) {
    this.start = function() {
      //hide start buttun and show other pause
      startButton.style.display = 'none';
      pause.style.display = 'unset';
      
      const then = new Date();
      const end = then.setMinutes(then.getMinutes() + sessionNumber2);

      currentInterval = setInterval(function() {
        //get Todays date and time
        let now = new Date().getTime();

        //find the distance between now and count down date
        distance = end - now;

        // Time calculations for minutes and seconds
        let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if (minutes < 10) {
          minutes = '0' + minutes;
          if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
          }
        }

        time.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        console.log(distance);
        //if over do something
        if (distance <= 0) {
          clearInterval(start);
          timeName.innerHTML = 'break';
          time.innerHTML = 'done';
        }
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  //paused
  this.paused = function() {
    pause.style.display = 'none';
    resume.style.display = 'unset';
    session = false;
    console.log(Boolean(session));
  }

  //resume
  this.resumed = function() {
    resume.style.display = 'none';
    pause.style.display = 'unset';
    session = true;
    console.log(Boolean(session));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your work. Edit your post and give your audience the answers to these questions: What did you find when you used your debugger to step through your code? What did you find when you used console.log() in some likely spots to make sure your variables have the values you would expect? What did you find when you stripped your code down to the barest thing that will run but still shows the problem? People will want to know what you've done toward solving the problem, and that you've given it due diligence before asking for help.

Comment: Before when I was using clearInterval to pause and it was working, to resume I tried to use the 'end' variable that I made that holds the time added to the current date that I'm counting down too, but everytime I did that the timer reset from the beginning.  I found that you can use a true or false to make it pause or resume too, but I'm not sure why this isn't working. the if else around a bit, I don't know what else to do to make it work but I'm still working on it just thought I'd post here to see if anyone knows.

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but you can find many many timers on npm. The one I use is https://www.npmjs.com/package/timrjs

Comment: I'm learning how to code on front end right now so I can't use npm, but thanks anyway.

Comment: the console isn't showing any errors, I'm not sure how to use the debugger. When I declare the resume and pause function they both show up in the console.

Comment: @kokokonoi You won't find many people who will want to help you if you haven't taken the time to learn how to use your debugger. I'm sure you're very likable, but no one wants to debug your code for you. Also, even if you don't know the debugger, you do know how to use `console.log()`. Sprinkle that around and see if the relevant variables have the values you expect them to have. And put some inside your if/else clauses to see whether you're even getting into them.

Comment: alright I got it. I was putting session to assign to true in my if statement and didn't realize it. thanks for replies. using === now. and put the if statement inside the set interval function. looks like this now setInterval(countDown, 1000) with the if statement inside countDown.

Answer (score 0):

As GreatBigBore noted, the answer to your question is debugging. Without debugging you'll have another problem an hour or two from now and find it very difficult to solve. `console.log()` is a very basic debugging tool; you want to graduate from that quickly. Chrome and Firefox both have great debuggers that let you actually stop the code at any point, view the values of variables, etc. Anytime you have an issue, start with the debugger. Find out what the value of different vars are, find out where the code actually goes step by step, etc. This is a good primer to debugging in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Good luck!

Edit - one additional note, something that will help you immensely in writing good code is something called "linting". Linting will tell you things like `hey you should use === instead of == here`. I'd say the industry standard nowadays is ESLint. If you want to learn to write really good, up to date code, set up ESLint :)

Comment: thanks, yeah I'm going to start using the firefox debugger. I just solved my answer but as you said, I'm already having other problems, but now because of debugging, new Date is causing problems which is an easy fix. I'm writing this on codepen so sorry for the bad indentation, it has no linter. Would use visual studio code usually.